# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Являются ли "спустя какое-то время" и "при возникновении определенных условий" однородными обстоятельствами или это единое целое?

Регулирующая арматура требует определенного расчета при проектировании, и ее неправильный расчет обязательно отразится на работоспособности ИТП в целом, причем проявиться это может спустя какое-то время (,) при возникновении определенных условий, а следовательно, проверка проектных решений задача непростая и неоднозначная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь нужна запятая или тире, поскольку последующий оборот уточняет предшествующий.
"Спустя какое-то время" = "не сразу". А когда? Тогда, когда возникнут условия, необходимые для такого проявления. Из начала фразы следует, что они обязательно возникнут, т.е. это вопрос "времени". Один способ указания "времени" уточняет или конкретизирует другой: "спустя какое-то время, (а наступит это время) при возникновении определенных условий", либо "спустя какое-то время (, а конкретно) - при возникновении определенных условий".

И ещё полезно тире после "решений".

Comment: Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном Вами примере, запятая не требуется, так как обороты "спустя какое-то время" ''при возникновении определенных условий" не являются однородными (это разные обстоятельства - времени и условия). А вот тире нужно: проверка проектных решений - задача непростая и неоднозначная.